# Making a has_many/belongs_to association immutable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I have an invoice class that has many items related to it. How can I make sure that after the invoice is saved no items can be added or deleted from the invoice?

I already use the [immutable attributes plugin](http://github.com/JackDanger/immutable_attributes/tree/master) to handle regular fields but it doesn't handle associations. Using attr_readonly doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

has_many has a :readonly option, which makes all items of the collection immutable ([api-link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001833)). However, unfortunately, this doesn't seem to prevent creation of new items.

```
class Invoice
  has_many :items, :readonly => true
end
```

To really make the collection immutable from within the `Invoice` class, you can redefine the `items` accessor and `#freeze` the collection for existing records:

```
class Invoice
  def items_with_immutability
    items = items_without_immutability
    items.freeze unless new_record?
    items
  end
  alias_method_chain :items, :immutability
end
```

Comment: That indeed prevents me from adding new items using << and friends. However, I can still call destroy on the associated items. :readonly => true only prevents saving, which is rather odd.

Comment: Freezing each record of the colletion should prevent that (untested):
    items.each(&:freeze) unless new_record?

However this is getting more and more ugly code. Maybe you should just use unit tests to make sure that items are not modified anywhere.